# Azure security center recommandation: issues installing endpoint protection

Tags: windows, azure, rbac

i am having a hard time with applying the recommandations of the Azure security center for my Windows VMs: it asks to install endpoint protection, but the issue is that whenever i try to install it for one of my vms, the creation fails, saying that i have an RBAC issue . The account i'm using has admin rights and ownership on every resource/subscription/vm/whatsoever, so i can't see why it keeps whining..can anybody bring me some help ?

Has anybody ever succeeded to setup the endpoint protection from the azure security center and if so, how did he/she do to succeed ? thank you very much !

Comment: Are you using Server 2016 by any chance?

Comment: Did you enable the RBAC on the Azure?

Answer (score 1):

> Has anybody ever succeeded to setup the endpoint protection from the azure security center and if so, how did he/she do to succeed ?

I didn't encounter any issue when I deploy the endpoint protection.

[image: start]

[image: success]

The endpoint protection is deployed as an extension. Deployments of extensions are handled by VM agent. To troubleshoot this issue, please check the log of Azure VM agent. The path of this log is "C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\WappAgent.log"

[image: log]